# How to convert jquery animation to movie or gif format?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ffmpeg, mp4

How to convert jquery animation to movie or gif format ?
Animation and screenshot functions call or too slow.
Help me please

Animation Function

```
function resim1(){
    $("#resim-1").animate({ left: leftx}, startEffectTime1);
    ......
}
```

ScreenShot Function but too slow

```
function shot(){
          html2canvas($("#main"), {
              onrendered: function(canvas) {
                  theCanvas = canvas;
                  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                  Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                  $("#img-out").append(canvas);
              }
          });
}
```

Call animation and screenshot functions

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     resim1(); // Animate start
     setInterval(function(){ // Screenshot start
          shot();
     },500);

});
```

Bottom function call animation breaking :/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     resim1(); // Animate start
     setInterval(function(){ // Screenshot start
          shot();
     },500);

});
```